# How to escape environment properties in Bash script on DevOps pipeline in Bluemix?

Tags: bash, escaping, ibm-cloud

In my DevOps pipeline in Bluemix I added a deploy stage with the **IBM Container on Bluemix** deploy type. I forked and modified the standard deployscript from [Osthanes](https://github.com/Osthanes/deployscripts). In the **Optional deploy arguments** I added the following:

```
--env GITHUB_USER=${GITHUB_USER}
--env GITHUB_PASSWORD=${GITHUB_PASSWORD}
```

Then I changed the URL to the Github repo in the **deployer script** to:

```
https://${GITHUB_USER}:${GITHUB_PASSWORD}@github.com/[...]/deployscripts.git
```

Then in the **Environment properties**-tab I added the variables for user and password. Now, I get the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://****:****@github.com/***/deployscripts.git/': Could not resolve host: abc@github.com

Where **abc** is the part of the password after an @-sign. I think that the @-sign in the password isn't masked properly, and so the URL isn't recognized properly.
If I change the @-sign to `%40` or escape it like `foo\@bar`, the `%` and the `\` are recognized as part of the password and Github won't let me in. Does anybody know how I can achieve that?
Btw. I have no rights to change the password ;)

Comment: Have you tried double-quoting your variables (eg. `"${GITHUB_USER}"`)?...

Comment: You should double quote the whole of the URL, in particular the square brackets `[...]` will be expanded by the shell as a glob construct.

Comment: @cdarke The square brackets are just a placeholder for the organization where the repository is.

Comment: @l'L'l I will try this. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, also I would take cdarkes advice (enclose the entire url in double quotes)...

Comment: @cbarke I get the same error message with quoting the entire url, and also with quoting just the variables.

Comment: @HugoB.: What happens when you don't use a variable and try using a regular URL, does it work?

Comment: @l'L'l The standard deploy script is a public repository with a regular URL, this works fine. Also if I make my repo public, it works. But due to client restrictions, I am not allowed to make it public.